# I can't access modified window.location object jest in another module

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I want to mock `window.location.search`.

config.test.js

```
import config from './config'
import { MULTIPLE_VIDEOS } from './Constants/flagKeys'

describe('', () => {
  const flag = { [MULTIPLE_VIDEOS]: true }

  global.window = Object.create(window)

  Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
    value: {}
  })

  afterAll(() => {
    global.window = null
  })

  it('Mark query string flag as true', () => {
    global.window.location.search = `?${MULTIPLE_VIDEOS}=true`
    expect(config.flags).toEqual(flag)
  })
})
```

config.js

```
export default { flags: getFlagsFromQueryString() }

function getFlagsFromQueryString () {
  const queryString = qs.parse(window.location.search.slice(1))
  const flags = {}

  Object.entries(queryString).forEach(([name, value]) => {
    flags[name] = value.toLowerCase() === 'true'
  })

  return flags
}
```

Though I set search value in location object before calling `config.flags`, I can't access it inside the function, It always returns empty string.

I want `window.location.search.slice(1)` to return `?multipleVideos=true` inside `getFlagsFromQueryString` function instead of empty string, since I changed the value in the test file.

One thing I noticed, when I export the function and call in the test file it works.

Answer (score 1):

***For this type of complex uses. I would recommend you to create a Window service/util class and expose methods from there. easy to test and mock.***

Sample:

**// Window.js**

```
class Window {
  constructor(configs) {}
  navigate(href) {
    window.location.href = href;
  }
}
export default new Window({});
```

Now you can easily mock `Window.js`. It is similar to DI pattern.